# Drupal with nginx : 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: drupal, nginx, centos

I have installed nginx on centos. When I try to open a website I get this error:

`500 Internal Server Error`

Error log:

```
2012/11/01 14:10:38 [error] 4552#0: *32 open() "/var/www/mywebsite.com/web/error/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.com"
2012/11/01 14:10:38 [error] 4552#0: *32 open() "/var/www/mywebsite.com/web/error/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.com"
2012/11/01 14:10:38 [error] 4552#0: *32 open() "/var/www/mywebsite.com/web/error/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.com"
2012/11/01 14:10:38 [error] 4552#0: *32 open() "/var/www/mywebsite.com/web/error/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.com"
2012/11/01 14:10:38 [error] 4552#0: *32 open() "/var/www/mywebsite.com/web/error/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.com"
2012/11/01 14:10:38 [error] 4552#0: *32 open() "/var/www/mywebsite.com/web/error/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.com"
2012/11/01 14:10:38 [error] 4552#0: *32 open() "/var/www/mywebsite.com/web/error/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.com"
2012/11/01 14:10:38 [error] 4552#0: *32 open() "/var/www/mywebsite.com/web/error/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.com"
2012/11/01 14:10:38 [error] 4552#0: *32 open() "/var/www/mywebsite.com/web/error/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.com"
2012/11/01 14:10:38 [error] 4552#0: *32 open() "/var/www/mywebsite.com/web/error/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.com"
2012/11/01 14:10:38 [error] 4552#0: *32 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/error/404.html", client: xx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.com"
```

nginx.conf (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf)

```
#######################################################################
#
# This is the main Nginx configuration file.  
#
# More information about the configuration options is available on 
#   * the English wiki - http://wiki.nginx.org/Main
#   * the Russian documentation - http://sysoev.ru/nginx/
#
#######################################################################

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main Module - directives that cover basic functionality
#
#   http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpMainModule
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Events Module 
#
#   http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpEventsModule
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# HTTP Core Module
#
#   http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule 
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    ## Detect when HTTPS is used
    map $scheme $fastcgi_https {
      default off;
      https on;
    }

}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/100-mysite.vhost

```
server {
        listen *:80;


        server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com www.mywebsite2.com mywebsite2.com;

        root   /var/www/mywebsite.com/web;



        index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;



        error_page 400 /error/400.html;
        error_page 401 /error/401.html;
        error_page 403 /error/403.html;
        error_page 404 /error/404.html;
        error_page 405 /error/405.html;
        error_page 500 /error/500.html;
        error_page 502 /error/502.html;
        error_page 503 /error/503.html;
        recursive_error_pages on;
        location = /error/400.html {
            internal;
        }
        location = /error/401.html {
            internal;
        }
        location = /error/403.html {
            internal;
        }
        location = /error/404.html {
            internal;
        }
        location = /error/405.html {
            internal;
        }
        location = /error/500.html {
            internal;
        }
        location = /error/502.html {
            internal;
        }
        location = /error/503.html {
            internal;
        }

        error_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/mywebsite.com/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/mywebsite.com/access.log combined;

        ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location /stats {
            index index.html index.php;
            auth_basic "Members Only";
            auth_basic_user_file /var/www/clients/client2/web3/.htpasswd_stats;
        }

        location ^~ /awstats-icon {
            alias /usr/share/awstats/icon;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            ##try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9012;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }





}
```

I tested php with replacing content of `index.php` with `<?php phpinfo();` and there is no problem.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you get anything in your error log?

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja Please see top of the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified a 404 error page that does not exist. Try creating one in `/var/www/mywebsite.com/web/error/404.html` and see if it starts working.

Comment: And `recursive_error_pages` switched on, that's why it results in a loop.